# Which message could applescript tell the application?

Tags: applescript

When I want to do something with **Finder**, I use

```
tell application "finder"
      do something
   end tell
```

Is there a function list that **finder** can do?

Or for other application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In AppleScript the terminology of the applications is listed in dictionaries

In Script Editor select menu item `File > Open Dictionary…` or press `Shift Cmd O`.
Then choose `Finder` or another application